# Mocking submodules in python getting error in submodule method call

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking

I'm trying to mock the subprocess module in my application

```
from subprocess import PIPE
import sys
from mock import MagicMock

from django.test import TestCase


def mockNMCLI(command_list, stdout, stderr):
    return {'communicate': (lambda: ("hello", ""))}


def mockPipe():
    return PIPE


sys.modules['subprocess'] = MagicMock()
sys.modules['subprocess.Popen'] = mockNMCLI
sys.modules['subprocess.PIPE'] = mockPipe


from robot_configuration_interface.helpers import network_manager # NOQA

class NetworkManagerTestCase(TestCase):  
    def test_list_available_networks(self):
       self.assertIsInstance(network_manager.list_connections(), (list))
```

---

This is the pertinant function and the imports from the module being tested.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
# ........
def list_connections():
    process = Popen(["nmcli", "-t", "-fields", "NAME,TYPE", "con", "list"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate() # <--- Here's the failure
    return stdout
```

However, this is failing with:

> ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack in process.communicate()

This clearly because Popen is not being mocked correctly. But why wouldn't it be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the package properly, in several ways:  don't patch by direct assignment in `sys.modules`, because that patch will not get undone afterwards and could break all sorts of things.

First of all, make a mock correctly, so that it knows how to *unpack:

```
>>> mock_popen = MagicMock()
>>> mock_popen.communicate.return_value = 'hello', 'world'
>>> stdout, stderr = mock_popen.communicate()
>>> stdout, stderr
('hello', 'world')
```

Then patch with a context-manager, something like this:

```
with mock.patch('path.where.you.import.Popen', mock_popen):
    the_code_that_uses_popen()
mock_popen.assert_called_with(...)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Updated the code, but I still can't get it to mock. I added it as a separate question, cause it's a giant bit of code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936606/patch-not-mocking-a-module