# Patch not mocking a module

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock `subprocess.Popen`. When I run the following code however, the mock is completely ignored and I'm not sure why

Test Code:

```
def test_bring_connection_up(self):
    # All settings should either overload the update or the run method
    mock_popen = MagicMock()
    mock_popen.return_value = {'communicate': (lambda: 'hello','world')}
    with patch('subprocess.Popen', mock_popen):
        self.assertEqual(network_manager.bring_connection_up("test"), "Error: Unknown connection: test.\n")
```

---

Module Code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
# ........
def list_connections():
    process = Popen(["nmcli", "-t", "-fields", "NAME,TYPE", "con", "list"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate() # <--- Here's the failure
    return stdout
```

Comment: What if you would change your import from `from subprocess import Popen` to `import subprocess` and then use `subprocess.Popen` in place of `Popen`?

Comment: I get the same result as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not patching in the right place.  You patch where `Popen` is defined:

```
with patch('subprocess.Popen', mock_popen):
```

You need to patch where `Popen` is imported, i.e. in the "Module Code" where you have written this line:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
```

I.e., it should look something like:

```
with patch('myapp.mymodule.Popen', mock_popen):
```

For a quick guide, read the section in the docs: [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Comment: Wait.. But how would I do that? the module will have it's own imports, right? If this is only for testing, how do I tell it to have different imports? Should I pass variables telling the module it's in testing mode and to import different information?

Comment: No, you don't modify the library code for the purposes of test.  You modify the test code to patch in the library code.  Please read the guide I've linked.